# PHP echo is not working when added AWS headers

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am working on a project where I have a server. The server connect to Amazon-Cognito to get Identity Id and token. here is my PHP code.

TEST.PHP:

```
include 'aws.phar';

//require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\CognitoIdentity\CognitoIdentityClient;
use Aws\Sts\StsClient;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;

echo "OK";

$Client = CognitoIdentityClient::factory(array(
  'version' => 'latest',
  'profile' => 'project1',
  'region'  => 'ap-northeast-1'
));

$result = $Client->getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(array(
  'IdentityPoolId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',

  'Logins' => array(
    'login.blupinch.app' => 'sandesh-004',
  ),
  'TokenDuration' => 3600,
));

echo $token = $result['Token'];
//echo null;
```

When I opened the browser and type the url of the server, I could only see the "OK" but not the value of `$token`. Interestingly, I could see "OK" and the `$token` value if I do this from the command line:

```
php test.php
```

Why is this happening?
Why can't I see the value of `$token`?

UPDATE:
when I run "php test.php". I can see the echo of token.like this

ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-222:/var/www/html$ php test.php

```
   OKeyJraWQiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1MiLCJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMToxMmJiZTJjOS0zMDZkLTRmY2ItOGY4Mi0yZmNlNjc3NmE1NjQiLCJhdWQiOiJhcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTphODcxZmE1Zi0yM2EyLTQ4MGQtYmFhNi1iNGVkMzE0MzcyNDQiLCJhbXIiOlsiYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZCIsImxvZ2luLmJsdXBpbmNoLmFwcCIsImxvZ2luLmJsdXBpbmNoLmFwcDphcC1ub3J0aGVhc3QtMTphODcxZmE1Zi0yM2EyLTQ4MGQtYmFhNi1iNGVkMzE0MzcyNDQ6c2FuZGVzaC0wMDQiXSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jb2duaXRvLWlkZW50aXR5LmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE0NTQ2ODczMzcsImlhdCI6MTQ1NDY4MzczN30.BSTYTw8bk27vuqHaElIjC1KdncJpQHQXpqJr3--eKGOIi1vq8rpTGuljm2XjNInCXvjjMTLxaG8ZN-gUHYdZGcvK6Bm9ts1Y_BPfOflVKjRU3rxemmY24gOQeb1xI0No6nvyhJW6MpkoOF2fGWmr79mL0J0PnepOQ4HxG_HJ6yGdrvRypFjDM7g7kLXvETeEYrJeDdvnYuoeh1sqRn7RkA9eea_5pq8Sbgk5bXhF1RUhLF_6pi-YMIu52-lLFZdbA0LxGTWrIKvZY-KhsKSBLt_A5ek52pXQSPJUcBFOVWgajVqpdBB7i-ls1IjLth0baLtCXgk1qsq52kDKWqvR6g
```

Comment: Check for connection errors

Comment: I tried to do curl "ip address" it is still shows OK. As I said it is working when I just run it from command line.

Answer (score 1):

By using the code

```
echo $token = $result['Token'];
```

You are simply echoing the boolean result of assigning value of $result['Token'] to $token.  It also looks like you should be referencing 'TokenDuration'

You need to do this

```
$token = $result['TokenDuration'];
echo $token;
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this not output true, which would be nothing.

```
echo $token = $result['Token'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $token = !empty($result['Token']) ? $result['Token'] : "Token is empty";
```